# changing x/y column without editing original ggplot command

Tags: r, ggplot2

(I will be using the `mtcars` dataframe from the `gcookbook` library.)

Let's say I generate the following plot:

```
p <- (ggplot(mtcars, aes (col = factor(cyl), x = wt, y = disp)) 
   + geom_point (shape = 19) 
   + geom_text (aes(y=disp+0.1,label=hp), size = 2.5, vjust=0) 
   + stat_smooth(method=lm))
plot(p)
```

[image]

Is there anyway I can change, for instance, the `x` or `y` or `col`, without having to go back and edit the original?

For instance, lets say I want to change `x` to `mpg` and `col` to `gear`. I'd like to just run something like,

```
p + ggplot(aes=aes (col = factor(gear), x = mpg))
plot(p)
```

but the first command gives the error:

```
Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot
```

Is there any way to change what columns are used in the plot without having to go back and edit the original command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the overall aesthetics for the plot, you can do:

```
p + aes(color = factor(gear), x = mpg)
```

To change the aesthetics of specific layers you can  manually change the object `p` by assigning new variables.  This seems fragile, though.

To change the aesthetic mapping for the `geom_text` layer in your example:

```
p$layers[[2]]$mapping$label = mtcars$wt
p$layers[[2]]$mapping$y = mtcars$disp + 2
```

Comment: Huh. OK... But now lets say I want to update `y` to `hp` and change the label to `disp`, without changing the font size? `p + aes (y=hp,label=disp)` doesn't change the labels, and `p + aes (y=hp,label=disp) + geom_text (aes(y=hp+0.3,label=disp))` adds another set of labels instead of replacing them. And the font of the added labels is default...

Comment: @ipetrik Yes, I answered your question about changing the overall aesthetics of a plot.  I added a possible approach for changing individual layers, although it seems fragile to me.

Comment: Hmm... yes, thank you! I just wanted to see what more I could learn to do. :-)  You are right, that seems really ugly, but it is informative!